# Call back-end function from client-side with arguments to fill chart.js graph (vb.net, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, charts

I'm trying to call a vb.net back-end function so I can fill my chart.js Bar chart.

I know it is possible because I use this method to get the labels for the chart.

My problem is that when I try to call an other back-end function and pass it arguments, it gives me an error telling me this :

--> Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'statsType' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

What I want to do is call the javascript function when the dropdown value changes, get the value of the new selectedItem in the dropdown and call the back-end function with that value as an parameter to get the data to fill the chart.

Here's my code :
**Client side:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatsType" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Participation rate" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Refusal rate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No answer" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Declined" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Coming from somewhere else" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        initializeChart();
        $("[id*=ddlStatsType]").bind("change", function () {
            initializeChart();
        });
    });

    function initializeChart() {
        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

        var statsType = $("#ddlStatsType").val();

        var data = {
            labels: <%= GetSitesListStringBuilder() %>,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: <%= UpdateStatsType(statsType) %>                }
        ]
        };

        myNewChart.Bar(data, {
            scaleShowVerticalLines: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

Back-end code :

```
Public Function GetSitesListStringBuilder() As String
    Dim siteName As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

    Dim siteList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    For row As Integer = 0 To dtSiteStats.Rows.Count - 1
        siteName = dtSiteStats.Rows(row).Item(1).ToString
        siteList.Add(siteName)
    Next

    sb.Append("[")
    For i As Integer = 0 To siteList.Count - 1
        siteName = siteList(i)
        sb.Append("""")
        sb.Append(siteName.ToString)
        If i < siteList.Count - 1 Then
            sb.Append(""",")
        Else
            sb.Append("""")
        End If
    Next
    sb.Append("]")

    Return sb.ToString
End Function

Public Function UpdateStatsType(ByVal statsType As Integer) As String
    Dim resultString As String = ""

    Select Case statsType
        Case 1
            resultString = GetParticipationRate()
        Case 2
            resultString = GetRefusalRate()
        Case 3
            resultString = GetNoAnswerRate()
        Case 4
            resultString = GetParticipationToOtherSitesRate()
        Case 5
            resultString = GetParticipationFromOtherSitesRate()
    End Select

    Return resultString
End Function

Public Function GetParticipationRate() As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    sb.Append("[")
    For row As Integer = 0 To dtSiteStats.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim originalParticipants As Integer = CType(dtSiteStats.Rows(row).Item(3), Integer)
        Dim participantsFromOtherSite As Integer = CType(dtSiteStats.Rows(row).Item(5), Integer)
        Dim totalInvitationsSent As Integer = CType(dtSiteStats.Rows(row).Item(8), Integer)
        Dim participationRate As Integer = CInt(((originalParticipants + participantsFromOtherSite) / totalInvitationsSent) * 100)
        If row < dtSiteStats.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            sb.Append(participationRate)
            sb.Append(",")
        Else
            sb.Append(participationRate)
        End If
    Next
    sb.Append("]")

    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Any help would be really appreciated. If something is not clear in my description of my issue, let me know and i'll clarify !

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint on this line  data: <%= UpdateStatsType(statsType) %>  and check the value of statsType?? Can you add also the back-end function.

Comment: I used the console in GoogleChrome and confirmed that statsType really gets the correct value from the dropdown. Also added the back-end code to my question ! :)

Comment: Try decorating your method with <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> attribute and make it a static(shared) method.